# How to save function in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Hi so i've tried to make my first function. A simple one that will restart powershell in windows terminal. And it's working.

```
function Restart-PowerShell{
Get-Process -Id $PID | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Command { & "$_" } -NoNewScope }
```

But when i restart powershell the function disappear, it doesn't save it. How can i save it? I've tried to look around but couldn't find any way to save

Answer (score 2):

You save PowerShell functions by simply putting their definition in a file on disk:

```
"function Restart-PowerShell {${function:Restart-PowerShell}}" |Set-Content Restart-PowerShell.ps1
```

This will write it to a file `Restart-PowerShell.ps1` in the current directory.

Next time you need to re-use your function, it's as simple as [dot-sourcing the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing):

```
PS ~> . .\path\to\Restart-PowerShell.ps1
PS ~> Restart-PowerShell # now the function is available in the current session
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69725290/45375) shows how to save your function's definition to a custom file that you can dot-source *on demand* in future sessions.

However, there is **a file that is dot-sourced *automatically* when a PowerShell session starts** (unless explicitly suppressed with `-NoProfile` via the PowerShell CLI): **your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)**, and that's where customizations of your sessions - such as custom functions and aliases - are typically stored.

Therefore, if you **add your function to your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)**, it automatically **becomes available in *future* sessions too**.

You can open `$PROFILE` in your text editor or, building on Mathias' technique,  **add the function *programmatically***, as follows, which ensures on-demand creation of the file and its parent directory (on a pristine machine, neither exists):

```bash
# Make sure the $PROFILE file exists.
If (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) { $null = New-Item -Force $PROFILE }

# Append the function definition to it.
@"

function Restart-PowerShell { 
  ${function:Restart-PowerShell}
}
"@ | Add-Content $PROFILE
```

Note: To reload your profile mid-session after having modified `$PROFILE`, use `. $PROFILE`.